# Accessing AWS through PynamoDB vs. low-level botocore

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, botocore

I have configured the AWS CLI properly following instructions and I want to access a DynamoDB table from the high-level package [PynamoDB](https://github.com/jlafon/PynamoDB) rather than boto3.

If I try to access my AWS cluster through the low-level *botocore* package, which is used by both boto3 and PynamoDB, and connect to a DynamoDB table as

```
import botocore.session
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('dynamodb')
client.describe_table(TableName='my_table_name')
```

all is OK, the table gets accessed fine.

But, I am trying to access through PynamoDB by following the tutorial in the documentation and creating a model for the table, as

```
from pynamodb.models import Model

class MyTableModel(Model):

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'my_table_name'

    pk_field = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    field1 = UnicodeAttribute()
    field2 = UnicodeAttribute()
```

and again describing the table through the appropriate method on the model

```
print MyTableModel.describe_table()
```

I get error

> pynamodb.exceptions.TableDoesNotExist: Table does not exist:
>   `Requested resource not found: Table: my_table_name not found`

I don't understand why as I have digged into the PynamoDB code and what I seem to understand is that it should call the same code from botocore and the configuration should be implicit.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @NoorJafri No, ended up reverting to using boto.

Comment: I fixed it by just explicitly mentioning the region in the MetaClass. Ill put my answer.

Comment: See this  pynomodb issue, as of the time of posting it's still open https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/issues/211

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hey I know it's pretty late by I was following up your thread with the same problem and just before going back to the boto I explicitly used the region as mentioned by @Jordon Phillips and it worked like a charm.

```
from pynamodb.models import Model

class MyTableModel(Model):

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'my_table_name'
        region = os.environ['Region'] #its region I get from serverless.yml

    pk_field = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    field1 = UnicodeAttribute()
    field2 = UnicodeAttribute()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a matter of a misconfigured region. Looks like pynamo doesn't respect the configured region, you have to explicitly pass it the region you want. Otherwise, you'll get `us-east-1`.

Comment: I've tried setting the region in Pynamo, same result.